# Meaning of 今日も一日？

Tags: meaning, phrases

> 仕事を終えた労働者が、ダンジョンから無事戻ってきた冒険者達が、**今日も一日**の締めくくりとばかりに酒盛りに耽っている。

This is the first time I have come across this. What exactly does it mean and how would I use it? I've seen it in other sentences too like:

> **今日も一日**頑張りましょう！

Comment: 今日も一日がんばるぞい！ https://www.google.co.jp/search?tbm=isch&q=%E4%BB%8A%E6%97%A5%E3%82%82%E4%B8%80%E6%97%A5%E3%81%8C%E3%82%93%E3%81%B0%E3%82%8B%E3%81%9E%E3%81%84

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have two very different 「今日{きょう}も一日{いちにち}」's here.

> 「**今日も一日**の締{し}めくくりとばかりに酒盛{さかも}りに耽{ふけ}っている。」

＝

> 「**今日も**、**一日**の締{し}めくくりとばかりに酒盛{さかも}りに耽{ふけ}っている。」

≒

> 「**一日**の締めくくりとばかりに、**今日も**酒盛りに耽っている。」

Here, 「今日も ("today also")」 and 「一日 (the "work" day)」 function separately and independently from each other.  Grammatically, it is ***not*** the same 「今日も一日」 that we use very often as a set phrase.

"***Today, too,*** (they are) indulged in a drinking party as if it were the closing ceremony of ***the day***."

Moving on...

The insanely common set phrase that I am talking about is the "other" 「今日も一日」 seen below.

> 「**今日も一日**頑張{がんば}りましょう！」

Here, 「今日も一日」 means "**today as usual**" or even just "**as always**".  It works adverbially.

"Let us work hard (today) ***as usual***!"

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an emphasis on 1日 when you say that 今日も１日　一生懸命に働こう.
That is, it means 
Let's work hard "for a whole day" today (as well as yesterday).